# angularjs ng-required not working on ios

Tags: ios, angularjs, validation

I am trying to use the `ng-required` in a form.
All I did was add `ng-required="true"` on my input.

In Chrome, when clicking submit it prevents submission and asks the user to fill the field, as expected. On an iPhone, it doesn't show any error and it executes the submit function.

```
<form name="addGuest" ng-submit="GLCtrl.addGuest()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newGuestFirstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="newGuestFirstName" ng-model="GLCtrl.newGuest.firstName" class="form-control" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newGuestLastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="newGuestLastName" ng-model="GLCtrl.newGuest.lastName" class="form-control" required="true"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="arrivalDate">Arrival Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="arrivalDate" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="GLCtrl.newGuest.arrivalDate" is-open="opened" required="true" close-text="Close"
      />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="GLCtrl.cancelAdd()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have the novalidate attribute in your form, and are you checking the validity of your form in your `submit` callback if form.$valid before continuing with the submission process?

Comment: No I don't have novalidate not am I checking $valid in my js. I guess that's part of my question, is it enough to use the angular parameters, or do I need to write the logic myself?

Comment: I found my solution, indeed I needed novalidate and `ng-submit="addGuest.$valid && GLCtrl.addGuest()"`

Comment: how are you showing your errors?

Comment: I wasn't. I guess the errors I was seeing were generated by Chrome itself.

Comment: hmm, I can see that you are using bootstrap-css, you can use `<span class="help-block"></span>` to show your errors and use `ng-show` when errors are present. Let me update my post and add a plunker.

Comment: If you are using the input element attribute "required" then no, it doesn't work on safari. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the form is valid before proceeding to your form submission process. In regards to your problem, you are probably relying on HTML5's `required` attribute which is added when `ng-required` is true. This might work on chrome but it partially works in IOS.

See the note on this **[link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)**

> Partial support in Safari refers to lack of notice when form with required fields is attempted to be submitted. Partial support in IE10 mobile refers to lack of warning when blocking submission.

Solution:

Add novalidate in your form, don't use the HTML5 required attribute messaging which is only useful for some browsers. Show required error message explicitly.

Sample HTML implementation:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit(form, user)">
  <input type="email" required name="email" ng-model="user.email">
  <div ng-show="form.email.$error.required>This field is required</div>
  <input type="password" required name="password" ng-model="user.password">
  <div ng-show="form.password.$error.required>This field is required</div>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Sample Controller implementation:

```
$scope.submit = function(form, user) {
  if(form.$valid) { // guard against any errors
   // do you login process here..
  }
};
```

Additionally, you can also use the `ng-disabled` approach to disable the submit button when when form is invalid.

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Login</button>
```

**UPDATE:**

This update takes into consideration that you are using twitter bootstrap3. By using the following classes: 'has-error' for form-groups and 'help-block' for showing the error messages. By using the `ng-class` and `ng-show` directives in showing the errors with angular form validation indicators mentioned in each angular input directives and the **[FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)** and **[NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)** documentation and also the guides shown in the **[developer's guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)**.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gHykeEcSN7cbwpYyCjqp?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit(form, guest)" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.firstName.$invalid && form.firstName.$dirty}">
    <label class="control-label" for="newGuestFirstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="newGuestFirstName" ng-model="guest.firstName" name="firstName" class="form-control" required="" />
    <div ng-if="form.firstName.$invalid && form.firstName.$dirty">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required">This field is required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.lastName.$invalid && form.lastName.$dirty}">
    <label class="control-label" for="newGuestLastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="newGuestLastName" ng-model="GLCtrl.newGuest.lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" required="" />
    <div ng-if="form.lastName.$invalid && form.lastName.$dirty">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.lastName.$error.required">This field is required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': form.arrivalDate.$invalid && form.arrivalDate.$dirty}">
    <label class="control-label" for="arrivalDate">Arrival Date</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="arrivalDate" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="arrivalDate" is-open="opened" name="arrivalDate" required close-text="Close" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="form.arrivalDate.$invalid && form.arrivalDate.$dirty">
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="form.arrivalDate.$error.required">This field is required</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
  </button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
  </button>
</form>
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

*Controller Logic submit()*

```
var fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'arrivalDate'];

$scope.submit = function(form, guest) {
  if(form.$valid) {
    // form is valid, do you form submission processhere..
  } else {
    angular.forEach(fields, function(field) {
      form[field].$dirty = true;
    });
  }
};
```